# Is there a man signature generator in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

Is there a plugin on jquery which you can create a signature or you can sign through computer without printing it and sign.

Comment: stackoverflow is not your search assistant.

Answer (score 2):

http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/

http://www.unbolt.net/jSignature/

....